# how record rosbag with python

Tags: rosbag, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I use the command line (Terminal) to record images (RGB, RGBD), joy, and IMU data

```
>> rosbag record -O subset /camera/depth/image_raw /camera/rgb/image_raw /joy /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw
```

How can I convert this command to python code script?

any help is appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286871/how-record-rosbag-with-python/) by [khadija](https://answers.ros.org/users/34050/khadija/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-03-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-28**:
Not a real answer (as this seems a bit of an xy-problem), but there is something called [osrf/nodelet_rosbag](https://github.com/osrf/nodelet_rosbag). That exposes an action server interface to `rosbag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The (ugly) way that I have done this in the past, is roughly like this:

```
import subprocess, shlex, psutil
command = "rosbag record -O subset /camera/depth/image_raw /camera/rgb/image_raw /joy /mobile_base/sensors/imu_data_raw"
command = shlex.split(command)
rosbag_proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

and this is how you can kill the recording process:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if "record" in proc.name() and set(command[2:]).issubset(proc.cmdline()):
        proc.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)

rosbag_proc.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-12-17**:
but send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT) didn't change .bag.active file to .bag file.

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2020-12-17**:
@azerila Check the newly edited answer. I have added a for loop for the created children "record" process.